# How to determine the transfer function of this pi filter?

Tags: filter, transfer-function, passive-filter, high-pass-filter

[image]

I have this pi filter, I wonder how do i determine the dynamic model and the transfer function of this filter?

Comment: It depends entirely on what you are using it for. For instance, is it used in a controlled impedance scenario? If so, then the answer will be different to a scenario where it isn't a controlled impedance scenario.